# How do I make a button transparent

Tags: javafx-2

I am making a javafx application where there's a border pane with a background image. The buttons on this border pane are supposed to be transparent. I can't seem to be able to accomplish this using blend modes and I can't. Please help me!!!
Sorry I can't post the code

Answer (score 1):

css :

```
.button{
     -fx-background-color: transparent; 
}
```

Javafx code :

```
Button buttonColor = new Button("Color");
buttonColor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

Answer (score -2):

you can simply using

```
button.setVisible(false);
```

to make it transparent, if you want to make it appears again, just using

```
button.setVisible(true);
```